# Can you pop function arguments in a Lua CFunction safely?

Tags: c++, parameters, lua, stack

I'm working on a very large framework exposing many algorithms, functions and features from C/C++ to Lua. This framework also exposes some functionality that works with tables, indexers, and often is merely a proxy for default behaviour if a certain condition is not true.

My question is very basic; Is it safe to pop function arguments from a C function in i.e. a newindex implementation in C? I currently implement it by getting an object which should hold the key and value and insert it before the key and value provided to the `__newindex` metamethod. I then use `lua_rawset` to set it to the object I placed in front, popping off two of the function arguments. Is this safe?

I ran extensive tests, including checkstack tests, and monitoring the top of the Lua stack. None of these tests are conclusive enough for me though, I would like to have the opinion of other Lua developers.

I've read many parts of the Lua documentation, however there does not seem to be a clear statement about this (or I have not found it). The manual (https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_CFunction) does state:

> Any other value in the stack below the results will be properly discarded by Lua.

However this doesn't answer my question if discarding these values myself can cause problems.

```cpp
// An example, is this safe to do? My guts say yes
int lm_entity__newindex(lua_State* L) {
    luaL_checkany(L, 1); // udata
    luaL_checkany(L, 2); // key
    luaL_checkany(L, 3); // value 

    // does not manipulate the stack, merely casts lua_touserdata
    auto entity = lm_entity(L, 1);

    // get the members table 
    lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, entity->members_ref);

    // place before key and value (lua_rotate)
    lua_insert(L, -3);

    // store, in turn popping the two function arguments
    lua_rawset(L, -3);

    // pop members table
    lua_pop(L, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect this to work safely, because in a function call the stack is restored afterwards based on the number of parameters passed on to the function and the number of return values pushed onto the stack. I'm not certain, though, that popping two of the arguments off the stack will cause issues in that regard, even though my testing seems to prove otherwise.

Comment: I'm not an expert on all the internals of Lua, but I don't see why popping arguments would cause problems. As far as I know, a Lua C function can do almost anything it likes to its portion of the stack.

Comment: I agree, that's what I would think too, however popping too many values might cause an issue - that's not the case here though. I just don't like making assumptions about these things, even though I have not encountered any problems in doing this yet.